# Problem In Getting Rinkeby Test Ethers

Tags: blockchain, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, rinkeby

I tried to get rinkeby ethers from https://faucet.rinkeby.io/ by creating a tweet but the website shows **"insufficient funds for gas * price + value”** error. I also tried the website faucets.blockxlabs.com, it shows the transaction to be successful but I didn't receive any rinkeby ethers. I am a newbie in working with test networks, any help would be appreciated. Thank u!

Comment: Post your address and I'll send you some

Comment: @SamuelDare 0x35B84d6848D16415177c64D64504663b998A6ab4

Comment: I'm currently following an Ethereum course on Udemy, and I really struggle to obtain some test ethers (I tried Rinkeby and Ropsten faucets, to no avail). All the answers I find online about that problem are of type "give me your address I'll send you some". It would be interesting to have a more general solution, or at least an an answer as to why it seems so hard to obtain test ethers in that particular time period.

Comment: The issue is now gone, I had the same problem. Just received my 3ETH by trying again.

Comment: @cjauvin Ultimately, it has to do with the fact that "test" money isn't going to be very useful for testing unless it acts like money to an extent and that means some form of limitation, which ironically means you won't be able to get it too easily.

Comment: I use this faucet: https://rinkebyfaucet.com/
Has never failed me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is on their side, when there is too much demand. There is nothing you can do other than trying some other day.

Today, it worked for me, where the other week I had the same issue as you.

Answer (score 0):

Testnet faucets tend to be really faulty.

1. [faucet.rinkeby.io](https://faucet.rinkeby.io/) -> I also had issues recently, but tried again right now and Facebook worked, while Twitter didn't.
2. [faucet.metamask.io](https://faucet.metamask.io/) -> never works during *standard* working hours and you will get the `{"error":"[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC` error. However, try to wake up early (<7:00am) or go to bed late (>2:00am) and it will probably work. You have a limit of 5 ETH per hour, but if you use a VPN and go changing IPs, you can get more...

Answer (score 0):

Alchemy has a reliable faucet, you just need to create an account with them https://rinkebyfaucet.com/ It's never left me down

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the Ropsten test network you can get as quick as eth into your account. But there is only a limit of 5eths request per 1hr.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As the OP asked for help with Rinkeby, answers should either directly help OP with the faucet on Rinkeby, or provide conclusive arguments for using a different testnet.